# Python 3 - How to create an variable that will become a new variable each time another variable updates

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

i would like to create an array that updates as a variable does.
eg in the form of

```
i = 1            //Just a starting variable 
while 1>0:       //To make it infinite to test the concept
    var(i) = i   //variable 1 first time around then variable 2 etc
    i = i + 1    //increase 1
```

but i am unable to do so and any help would be greatly appreciated

also will the given solution also apply if this was an array instead of a variable

Comment: can you explain more ? whats `var()` ?

Comment: var is just a stand in variable name, my question is how can i make an new array that keeps that same name but with a new number afterwards - var1, var2, var3, etc- i am trying to do this in a way that makes it possible to theoretically have an infinite number of stored variables that can all be created based on a starting name - (var) - and be changed with just a number

Comment: Don't try to make variables with data in their names: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) using `i` as a key:

```
var = {}                  # an empty dictionary
for i in range(1, 11):    # 1, 2, 3, ..., 10
    var[i] = i
```

This will results in dictionary `var` containing the following:

```
>>> print(var)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10}
```

Lookup items in the dictionary using a key:

```
>>> for i in range(1,6):
...     print(var[i])
```

You could also use a dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary:

```
var = {i:i for i in range(1,11)}
>>> print(var)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10}
```

An alternative is to use a Python list using `i` as an index:

```
var = []
for i in range(11):    # note list index is zero-based
    var.append(i)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
var = [i for i in range(11)]
```

Or via `list`:

```
var = list(range(11))
```

Then you can access your "variable" by index:

```
>>> print(var[5])
5
>>> print(var[9])
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a list or a dictionary:

```
vars = {}
i = 1
while True:
    vars[i] = i
    i += 1
```

or:

```
for i in range(1000):
    vars[i] = i
```